# ¿Y si pasamos a wiki todas las traducciones?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Estoy viendo que hay varios que están traduciendo preguntas del inglés al español. En casi todos los casos dicen hacerlo sin afán de obtener puntos y sólo con el propósito de ayudar a la comunidad. Incluso algunos específicamente han dicho que no tienen problema en que un moderador pase a `wiki` sus preguntas y respuestas de este estilo.

Algunas de esas preguntas auto respondidas incluso son `community wiki` en `SO en inglés`.

Imaginen, los que traducen y los que no estamos de acuerdo con que se ganen puntos por traducir deliberadamente estaríamos finalmente de acuerdo y esta comunidad crecería el doble de rápido (o más).

Personalmente daría `upvotes` a esas preguntas, comentaría, ayudaría a mejorar las traducciones, agregaría ejemplos y más.

¿Estarían de acuerdo en hacer esto (con las preguntas que apliquen)?
¿Habría algo malo? ¿Hay algún moderador que nos pudiera ayudar si esto se lleva a cabo?

Para más información (en inglés) de lo que es `community wiki` [ver acá](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Comment: Si es community wiki en SO, entonces debería ser community wiki en SOes. En cuanto a al resto, creo que también pueden aplicar.

Comment: Apoyo esta propuesta para desalentar las traducciones, quizá así veamos buenas preguntas y nadie mas se va a quejar de si es valida o no la reputación, puesto que no habría ganancia. Asi, traducir seria un acto altruista; aprobado y bien visto por toda la comunidad.

Comment: +1 por "Algunas de esas preguntas auto respondidas incluso son community wiki en SO en inglés.". Creo que es lo correcto haceer lo mismo

Comment: El voto se debe realizar en función de la calidad de la publicación. Usar otras consideraciones como si es community wiki, si la publicó una persona con afán de conseguir puntos, etc es irrelevante. Se vota a la calidad, nada más. [Como dice Shog9](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311408/1983854) (Community Coordinator de Stack Exchange), _Please, vote based on the value of the post. If you don't have an opinion on the value of a given post, then don't vote_.

Comment: +1, estoy en contra de hacerlas wiki. Pero es un tema a debatir importante y una pregunta muy relevante.

Answer (score 10):

Estoy de acuerdo con esta propuesta sin embargo creo que habría que tener las sgtes consideraciones:

#### Diferenciar la pregunta de la respuesta

Algunas veces solo la traducción corresponde a la pregunta y la respuesta es creada por otro usuario con su propia explicación sin tomar en cuenta alguna otra respuesta en stackoverflow en inglés u otro idioma.

#### Preguntas autorespondidas

Creo que en este caso no hay duda que tanto la pregunta como la respuesta pueden ser wiki de la comunidad

#### Preguntas que no son traducciones que tienen respuestas que sí son traducciones

En este caso mi opinión es que **no** se debe volver wiki de la comunidad.

La razón es que esas preguntas son totalmente genuinas y la respuesta probablemente ya existe en stackoverflow en inglés o ruso o cualquier otro o incluso un post en un blog inglés.

El hecho de responder una pregunta indicando la fuentes (traducido o no) es la escencia de stackoverflow y debe citarse el autor original. Si el texto es una traducción o no, no es importante, lo que cuenta es que el autor de la pregunta obtuvo su respuesta y esto es justamente lo que hace que el sitio sea valioso para los que llegan a resolver sus consultas

Comment: sobre el punto 3, la verdad es que en SO ya se hicieron _casi_ todas las preguntas posibles, es impracticable otra cosa.

Comment: @rnrneverdies si ya se hicieron todas las preguntas posibles ¿cómo es que siguen llegando a diario cientos (si no miles) de preguntas al día a enSO? (Descartando las cerradas por cualquier motivo y las de mala calidad)

Decir eso en un entorno tan cambiante como el de la programación es, cuando menos, ingenuo.

Comment: @JhonAlx dije _casi_ todas :)

Answer (score 3):

## Mejor NO. Pero debes ser experto técnico en lo que traduces.

Cuesta mucho tiempo hacer una buena traducción. Dejemos que la comunidad valore si es una buena contribución o no. [Que es lo que realmente son los puntos en Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.
>
> La reputación es una medida aproximada de cuánto confía la comunidad en ti; se consigue convenciendo a tus pares de que sabes de qué estás hablando.

No valoran si es traducido o no. Ni si es original o copiado.
Lo que valoran es si la comunidad confía en ti.
Si haces buenas traducciones de temas en que **eres experto** y que son útiles pues que te voten.
Si no sabes de qué estás hablando se notará cuando no seas capaz de atender dudas que surjan en los comentarios. Lleva un tiempo que esto se haga evidente y la puntuación lo refleje correctamente, pero acaba pasando.
Esto es un pilar fundamental del funcionamiento de SO, es muy improbable que que se cambie.

Eso sí, solo debes traducir aquello en lo que eres experto técnico. Es decir, que sabes del tema como para dar la respuesta por ti mismo pero es más rápido traducir la respuesta que redactarla tu mismo. O la respuesta que traduces está tan bien redactada o pulida por el paso del tiempo que cualquier cosa que redactases tu mismo resultaría un texto inferior.

---

Yo también tuve dudas al principio, pero tras experimentar lo que cuesta hacer una buena traducción y repasar cómo funciona SO las he resuelto.

Comment: Obviamente el que quiere traducir algo tiene que hacerlo sobre el tema que domina. Si cuesta mucho hacer una traducción o no es tema de la persona que desea hacerlo, se valora el esfuerzo para el apoyo a la **comunidad**

Comment: si fuera un foro de traducciones sería cool, pero es un foro técnico, si de traducir se trata mejor le digo a mi esposa que no sabe nada de este tema que traduzca todo y acumule más puntos que yo  que si hago aportes técnicos

Comment: @JuanK , No, no es un foro de traducciones, pero tampoco un foro técnico. De hecho no es un foro. En http://stackoverflow.com/tour :"Stack Overflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuesta para profesionales y programadores entusiastas". Lo cual incluye tanto preguntas y respuestas originales como traducidas, lo uno no excluye a lo otro. Quien traduce, siendo un experto técnico, no solo un conocedor del inglés, no disminuye las aportaciones de quien hace preguntas y respuestas originales. De las traducciones hechas por quienes no son expertos técnicos en el tema sí estoy en contra.

Answer (score 3):

No creo que esta sea una buena idea por un motivo simple:

## Esta idea desalienta una forma de crear contenido nuevo y hacer crecer nuestra comunidad.

Deberíamos enfocarnos mejorar nuestra comunidad -- no en crear este tipo de reglas que también le quitaría el premio a un segmento de nuestros usuarios que son buenos traductores y pueden brindarnos buen contenido.

Answer (score -2):

En lugar de tratar de legalizar lo mal hecho, hagamoslo bien desde el principio:

## Comparte tu conocimiento, no una traducción!

No me interesa si son CW, si se desasocian de la cuenta, o cualquier otra "solución" posible. No es un crecimiento orgánico de es.SO, y por lo tanto toxico.

Comment: Toxico *per se*, no lo creo... Como casi todo en esta vida, comportamientos toxicos son los comportamientos compulsivos. Pero, opino que mejor traduzir *nuestras mejores* respuestas (preguntas):

Comment: Y luego también, hay que estar muy aburrido para estar traduciendo cosas, cuando uno se puede divertir con códigos y desafíos originales. PS: en algún momento, me gustaría traer mis mejores respuestas pal site en español

Comment: -1. Una buena traducción de un tema relevante no perjudica a nadie y ayuda a muchos.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos Yo no voy a ser parte de esto entonces... no tendria sentido.

Comment: Muy de acuerdo, sino vamos a generar contenido propio entonces no hay propuesta de valor en tener SO en español porque la labor de traducción ya la pueden hacer medianamente bien los traductores online. Hay que atraer/premiar a quienes hacen aportes técnicos pero sí los top users son los que traducen artículos a nadie le va a interesar venir a hacer aportes acá.